# Laravel. Choosing whether I need pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

First model is person and second one is proxy. One person is using currently one proxy but he can change proxy. I need it to be saved in history in some way.
Persons table has proxy_id column and model code:

```
public function proxy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Proxy::class);
}
```

Proxy model:

```
public function persons()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Person::class);
}
```

Right now in proxies table I've got history column and save it as array of persons ids. Once person gets proxy it's id is saved in proxies table in this history column. To get proxyHistory() I loop through ids and find that person in persons table. On index page we need to see who is currently using the proxy and who ever used. So when I get a list of proxies with people who ever used them I get tons of db queries which I want to avoid. I was thinking of many-to-many and pivot table so that I could reference persons in one query as a relation but it's not exactly how many-to-many is usually used. If I just use pivot I don't know exactly which proxy is used by exact person right now. Also when giving a proxy to some person I also have some restrictions based on the current users of the proxy and on those who ever used it.
How could I implement this history concept? I hope it's understandable )

Comment: i think keep as it is and make new table `proxy_history` and add `person_id` and `proxy_id` it will be kind of pivot table but it will be only use to store history and get history